# Mongoose - multiple relations between objects

Tags: database-design, architecture, mongoose

Let's say I'm building a community blog engine:

- We have several categories `Category`
- We have many blogs `Blog`
- We have many posts `Post`
- We have may authors `Account`
- Every `Category` may contain several `Blog`'s
- Every `Blog` may be contained in several `Category`'s
- Every `Blog` may contain several `Post`'s
- Every `Post` may be contained in several `Blog`'s
- Every `Account` may be both `owner` and `editor` of a several `Blog`'s. That's why it may contain array of ObjectID's of several `Blog`'s in `owner` and `editor` fields.
- Every `Blog` may be owned and edited by several `Account`'s. That why it may contain array of ObjectID's of several `Account`'s in `owner` and `editor` fields.

Here's a schema:

```
categorySchema = mongoose.Schema(
  title: String
  blogs: [
    type: ObjectId
    ref: "Blog"
  ]
)

blogSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  title: String
  description: String
  owner:
    type: ObjectId
    ref: "Account"

  editor: [
    type: ObjectId
    ref: "Account"
  ]
  category: [
    type: ObjectId
    ref: "Category"
  ]
  posts: [
    type: ObjectId
    ref: "Post"
  ]
)
postSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  blogs: [
    type: ObjectId
    ref: "Blog"
  ]
  author:
    type: ObjectId
    ref: "Account"
)

accountSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  name: String
  owner: [
    type: ObjectId
    ref: "Blog"
  ]
  editor: [
    type: ObjectId
    ref: "Blog"
  ]
)
```

Every post may also contain likes, comments, and other objects, that may relate to only this object.

The problem is when I try to add new `Blog`, I'll have to manage a lot of fields in many collections. The same thing is when I edit `Blog`'s or delete – I have to to find, check, modify/remove a lot of records in various array fields in a lot of Objects.

I was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331682/mongoose-how-to-limit-depth-of-populate-level), I should not store direct relations (Categories --> Blogs, Blogs --> Posts), only reverse relations (Blogs --> Categores, Posts --> Blogs), and when I need to get all Blogs in certain Category, perform a simple `Blogs.find({category: cat_id})`, but think what will be if I need some **deep** request, such as `Get all Blogs where account_ID both owner and editor`. Assuming the fact there can be a lot of blogs and every blog may contain a lot of onwers and edtiors, direct `Blog.find {owner:acc_id, editor:acc_id}` will be way faster. That why I think I need 2-directional links.

So, my question is:

- Do I really need 2-directional links between objects?
- If yes, are there any tools to optimise working with it?

Maybe I should use some kind of many-to-many relations in Mongoose?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that you want to build relationships between the objects. May I ask why did you pick mongoDB. The whole point of it is that it is a noSQL db. This means that when you start developing a mongoDB app you should change your way of thinking. You need to be thinking not about relations but about articles. Every article should be complete. Once you start designing relations, you break the NoSQL model and you will hate mongoDB. You will be thinking it is the worst, and it is really not. So I'd say figure out your design and then decide on a database.

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need two way links.

All you need are

```
Blog->Category
Blog->Editors
Blog->Owners
Post->Blog
```

Because your categories and users never change object ids, then you don't have to worry about updating references inside of blogs. In addition, when you want to remove a blog, don't delete the records. Instead, add a flag that marks the blog as deleted. When you display content, just check the delete flag of the corresponding blog, or even add a condition to your query to avoid those results entirely. (This also has the benefit of preserving history)

To summarize, instead of creating two way links, you can just link from the more specific and changeable content to the more static content. To delete records, you either add a delete flag and don't worry about chasing records, or you can select all posts that have the blog_id in question and remove them first.